# Selecting a scalar value in a Firebird stored procedure

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I'd like to get the ID of a particular row from within a Firebird 2.1 stored procedure. I can't seem to remember the syntax, and it's driving me nuts.

This is how the code might look in TSQL, used by Microsoft SQL Server.

```
    @ID = SELECT ID FROM ADDRESS WHERE 
      POBox = :POBOX AND
      ExtendedAddress = :EXTENDEDADDRESS AND
      StreetAddress = :STREETADDRESS AND
      Locality = :LOCALITY AND
      Region = :REGION AND
      PostalCode = :POSTALCODE AND
      CountryName = :COUNTRYNAME;
```

What's the Firebird equivalent?

**UPDATE**: The [Firebird SQL migration guide](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-syntax.html) suggests that this should work

```
    SELECT ID INTO :ID FROM ADDRESS WHERE 
      POBox = :POBOX AND
      ExtendedAddress = :EXTENDEDADDRESS AND
      StreetAddress = :STREETADDRESS AND
      Locality = :LOCALITY AND
      Region = :REGION AND
      PostalCode = :POSTALCODE AND
      CountryName = :COUNTRYNAME;
```

But I get a syntax error at "INTO" when I try to create the stored proc.

Comment: For posterity, what version of FB?

Comment: I'm using Firebird 2.1 and 2.5. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the Firebird migration guide is wrong. This syntax worked for me:

```
SELECT ID FROM ADDRESS WHERE 
   POBox = :POBOX AND
   ExtendedAddress = :EXTENDEDADDRESS AND
   StreetAddress = :STREETADDRESS AND
   Locality = :LOCALITY AND
   Region = :REGION AND
   PostalCode = :POSTALCODE AND
   CountryName = :COUNTRYNAME
INTO :ID;
```

Note that the `INTO` clause must come *after* the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: You're right, @mghie! Silly cut and paste error. I've corrected my answer.